# PHP: filter_var sanitization secure enough?

Tags: php, security

I have a PHP script with the following line:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id='" . filter_var($_GET[id], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) . "'";
```

Is this safe enough? How would you improve this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe for that case, but for a more general approach, I'd rather use `mysql_real_escape_string` in conjunction with type casting:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id='" . (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'";
```

In the worst case, that will result in a `0` and will escape all malicious input also. `mysql_real_escape_string` can be used on all kinds of data to make it safe for queries, which makes it the most versatile of all escape/sanitation functions.

Without going as far as using prepared statements, you can use sprintf to create your SQL and to handle the type casting automatically:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '%d'", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
```

See the [sprintf](http://fi.php.net/sprintf) entry from the PHP manual for the syntax.

It gets even simpler if you use `array_map` to escape all `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables, then you can use them as is:

```
$_GET = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET);
$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '%d'", $_GET['id']);
```

Comment: +1, also there is better support for this since filter_var is only available on PHP 5.2 or higher.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just use [intval](http://php.net/intval):

```
$product_id = intval($_GET['id']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id='" . $product_id . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this works for you...!

```
$query=query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id= ". escape_string($_GET['id']) . " ");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.